# Export Data table With Arabic Data to Excel

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I am Having a Data Table which consists of arabic data.
When I am Exporting it to excel I am unable to get the Arabic data correctly.

Currently my code is as below,

```
  public void ExportExcel(DataTable table, string filename)
    {
        if (table != null && filename != "")
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";               
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
            new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            GridView GrdExcel = new GridView();
            GrdExcel.AllowPaging = false;
            GrdExcel.DataSource = table;
            GrdExcel.DataBind();
            for (int i = 0; i < GrdExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                GridViewRow row = GrdExcel.Rows[i];                   
                row.Attributes.Add("class", "text");
            }
            GrdExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


        }

    }
```

EDIT 1:

Below is the final code which has worked for me

```
             ////If you want the option to open the Excel file without saving than

             ////comment out the line below

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";


            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
            new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            DataGrid grdExcel = new DataGrid();
            grdExcel.AllowPaging = false;
            grdExcel.DataSource = table;
            grdExcel.DataBind();
            foreach (DataGridItem i in grdExcel.Items)
            {

                foreach (TableCell tc in i.Cells)
                    tc.Attributes.Add("class", "text");

            }
            grdExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style> ";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(style);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

This was written by referring few articles from the web .Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: It worked for me!! I have edited my question with the new code which worked for me ..cheers

Answer (score 0):

Every string wrap in `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` (for ex: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(str)`)

and in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="he-IL"/>
</system.web>
```

he-IL is in my case, write your language culture respectively