# Exporting HTML table to Excel in aspx page with arabic content

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, excel

I wrote code using Ajax/C# that will append data with jQuery to HTML table ,this is the table headers:

```
table id='tblUsers' class='table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-responsive' >      
             <tr>
                   <th>Customer ID</th>
                   <th>Customer Name</th>
                   <th>File #</th>
                   <th>Territory</th>
                   <th>Start Date</th>
                   <th>Goods Desc</th>
                   <th>Custom Declaration</th>
                   <th>Quantity</th>
                   <th>Weight</th>
                   <th>Volumetric Weight</th>
                   <th>Mortage Amount</th>
                   <th>Invoice#</th>
                   <th>Invoice Amount</th>
             </tr>
     </table>
```

and this is the Ajax Call:

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: "WebService.asmx/showResult",
                        type: "post",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            "dateFrom": $('#txtDateFrom').val(),
                            "dateTo": $('#txtDateTo').val(),
                            "ddlType": $("#ddlType").children("option").filter(":selected").val(),
                            "ddlTer": $("#ddlTer").children("option").filter(":selected").val(),
                            "ddlFilter": $("#filter").children("option").filter(":selected").val()
                        }), // parameters
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $('#loader').html('<img src="Images/loading.gif" />');


                        },

                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#loader').html('');
                            document.getElementById('filter').style.display = 'inherit';
                            document.getElementById('logo').style.display = 'none';
                            document.getElementById('exp').style.display = 'inherit';
                            //To delete the whole tr except the first one.
                            $("#tblUsers").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                            $('#tblUsers').append(JSON.stringify(result));
                            if ($("#ddlType").val() != 0) {
                                document.getElementById('filter').style.display = 'none';

                            }

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('error');
                        }


                    });
```

The WebMethod:

```
      var sp = db.divideTypes(dateFrom, dateTo, ddlFilter).ToList();
      foreach (var u in sp)
      {
            result += "<tr>";

            result += "<td>" + u.custid + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.custname + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.depno + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.Terr + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.deidate + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.gooddesc+ "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.custdec + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.pkg + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.wt + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.vwt + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.lcamt+ "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.invno + "</td>";
            result += "<td>" + u.invamt + "</td>";
            result += "<td></td>";

            result += "</tr>";
      }
```

i tried to read articles over the web to export excel table as excel file but
using JQuery, [How to export HTML table data to excel sheet using Jquery](http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/)

Heading

and there's a lot of articles like this all of them failed because i want to render Arabic letters so the letters looks strange.

i notice that there's an article in stackOverflow:[Export Data table With Arabic Data to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988417/export-data-table-with-arabic-data-to-excel)

that talk about a situation similar to mine, but really i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @mybirthname
Thanks for your comment, i explained my problem.

Comment: No one Can help me with this issue?